# Linker Command Failed Facebook Sdk

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, linker-errors, bolts-framework

I am new to iOS and trying to implement Facebook SDK in a project using AppGuru Facebook integration in Swift tutorial. But I am facing this linker command error while building my app:

> error is framework not found Bolts for architecture x84_64(linker command failed with exit code 1)

Here is a screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Download demo project with facebook login from below URL. you have to configure your facebook app id.

**[Download](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7ooURy3zGWKQVZ3UE1NR3RjajQ/view?usp=sharing)**

You have to import this 3 frameworks in your project.

**Check on this**

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios

**Framework search path - add below line**

**$(PROJECT_DIR)/Projectname/FacebookSDK**

[image]

---

Also check, bolts, core and login kit of facebook has to be in build phase -> Link binary with libraries

[image]

Comment: Take a screen shot and update in your question. if you have imported bolts then it has to be work.

Comment: Strange! In Facebook documentation not mentioned about "Bolts.framewok". But fine issue fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Follow steps -

- Go to your `project setting` page
- Select `your project` (left side)
- Click the `Build Settings` tab
- Search `Bitcode`
- Set `Enable Bitcode` to `No`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. I deleted the `ParseFacebookUtils.framework` library from my project and kept only the `ParseFacebookUtilsV4.framework`.

Answer (score 0):

When using the AWS Mobile SDK for iOS and Facebook SDK together, you should not import Bolts.framework in your project. If you remove it, it should compile.

Comment: no i didn't import bolts framework. I just make empty project and import Facebook sdk (FBSDKcorekit.framework and FBSDK Login kit framework only) as in tuts and do same process as told but this error is coming

Answer (score 0):

Copy the frameworks into the project but, unlike what Facebook tutorial suggests, select "Copy items into destination group's folder". I did that and it worked fine for me.